# Find all 6 month start and end dates between dates javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have situation to split up every 6months between start end dates using javascript. Consider the following example,

Start Date:11/08/2018 (mm/dd/yyyy)
End Date : 01/20/2020

Need following breakup

```
From        To          Note
11/08/2018  12/31/2018  here 11/08/2018 and 12/31/2018 comes between July to Dec which is second half of year
01/01/2019  06/30/2019  here 01/01/2019 and 06/30/2019 comes between Jan - June which is first half of year
07/01/2019  12/31/2019  here 07/01/2019 and 12/31/2019 comes between July to Dec which is second half of year
01/01/2020  01/20/2020  here 01/01/2020 and 01/20/2020 comes between Jan - Jun which is first half year
```

Please advise

Comment: Is using momentjs an option for you?

Comment: @rainerh I have updated the example comments, please look and advise. if needed i can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps http://plnkr.co/edit/hgEyiLyrX3Lfa7NJTeaL:

```
  var startDate = moment('11/08/2018');
  var endDate = moment('01/20/2020');


  function splitHalfYear(startDate, endDate) {
    var startMonth = startDate.month();
    var currentDate = moment(startDate);
    var returner = [];
    if (startMonth < 6) {
      currentDate = currentDate.startOf('year').add('month', 6);
    }
    else {
      currentDate = currentDate.startOf('year').add('year', 1);
    }

    returner.push({from: startDate, to: moment(currentDate).subtract('second', 1)});

    while(currentDate <= endDate) {
      var from = moment(currentDate);
      currentDate = currentDate.add('month', 6);

      if (currentDate.isAfter(endDate)) {
        returner.push({from: from, to: endDate});
      }
      else {
        returner.push({from: from, to: moment(currentDate).subtract('second', 1)});
      }
    }

    return returner;
  }


  var dates = splitHalfYear(startDate, endDate);
  dates.forEach(function(interval) {
    document.write(interval.from.format() +' - ');
    document.write(interval.to.format() + '<br>');
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, but end date column should show previous date

Comment: OK, I've subtracted a second from the end date

Comment: try var startDate = moment('01/08/2018'); var endDate = moment('05/20/2018'); comes wrong like 2018-01-08T00:00:00+05:30 - 2017-12-31T23:59:58+05:30
2017-12-31T23:59:59+05:30 - 2018-05-20T00:00:00+05:30

Comment: Thanks,I think this should be like this  currentDate = currentDate.startOf('month').add('month', 6- startMonth);

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily with `momentjs` like below:

```
var beforeSixMonths = moment().subtract(6,'months');
var today = moment();

// and use like below for your other needs
var afterSixMonths = moment().add(6,'months');
```

For more details you can read [docs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple snippet that iterates the Date. Then you can add the code you want:

```
var start = "11/08/2018";
var end = "01/20/2020";

var sd = new Date(start); //sd from starting date
var ed = new Date(end); //ed from end date

var months_interval = 6;
console.log("----------");
while(true){
    if(sd>ed){ //if adding 6 months is higher than end date.
        console.log("from: "+sd);
        console.log("to: "+ed);
        break;
    }else{
        console.log("from: "+sd);
        sd.setMonth(sd.getMonth()+months_interval); //add 6 months
        console.log("to: "+sd);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ma714sb/

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: Here's another code if you want it with recursion:

```
var start = "11/08/2018";
var end = "01/20/2020";

var sd = new Date(start); //sd from starting date
var ed = new Date(end); //ed from end date

var months_interval = 6;
console.log("----------");
iterate(sd,ed);

function iterate(sd,ed){
    if(sd>ed){
        console.log("FROM: "+sd+" TO: "+ed);
        return;
    }else{
        var new_sd = new Date(sd)
        new_sd.setMonth(new_sd.getMonth()+months_interval);
        console.log("FROM: "+sd+" TO: "+new_sd);
        iterate(new_sd,ed);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ma714sb/1/

Comment: thanks, please check the given requirement in table. need breakup based on first half and second year :)